# Always getting first img instead of img after specified div id?

Tags: perl, cgi, screen-scraping

I am creating a basic screen scraper and have done so successfully but for some reason this portion of code will not grab the intended img tag.  I am trying to grab the img src after the div with the specified id, but the script is grabbing the first img tag on the page.
For example, this sample comic scraper

```
$agent->get("http://www.blondie.com/todays_strip/");
$stream = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$agent->{content});

$tag = $stream->get_tag("div");

while ($tag->[1]{id} and $tag->[1]{id} ne 'comicpanel') {
    $tag = $stream->get_tag("div");
}

my $blondie_comic = $stream->get_tag("img");

print $cgi->h1("$blondie_comic->[1]{'src'}");
```

The above snippet just prints the src for the first image tag it comes across, the logo, instead of continuing on to the comic strip img.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need

```
while (not exists $tag->[1]{id} or $tag->[1]{id} ne '<specified-id>') {
  $tag = $stream->get_tag("div");
}
```

You want to check if the id exists before checking if it does not equal your specified id. You cannot use `and` because a tag that doesn't exists will be false and will break your loop early.

Here's the file I used to test. An id of 1 is the specified id:

```
<div id='2'>
<img src="NOPE" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="NOPE - 2" />
</div>
<div id='1'>
<img src="YEP" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nate... but still no go for some reason.  I've updated my original question to include a simple scrape that is acting awkward, how I described.

Comment: Okay. Could you post a simplified HTML example of the data you're looking at? That could help identify the problem.